# ArrayList in HashMap using a method in Java

Tags: java, methods, dictionary, arraylist, hashmap

I have a HashMap with ArrayList as values:

```
HashMap <String, ArrayList<String>> Test

    ArrayList<String> fruit = new ArrayList<>();
    fruit.add("bananas"); 
    fruit.add("apples");

    Test.put("fruit", fruit);


    ArrayList<String> cities = new ArrayList<>();
    cities.add("London"); 
    cities.add("Paris");

    Test.put("cities", cities);
```

I want to access the first element of each ArrayList, but using a **method**. For example something like that:

```
public String getSomething (ArrayList<String> Something) {
return (Test.get(Something)).get(1);
}
```

But this is not working as `'Something'` must be an ArrayList. Any ideas about that? Is there another way of accessing a HashMap with multiple values for one key?

Comment: Isn't the String the key, and the ArrayList the object that would be retrieved?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to pass to the method? is it Test? That's a no no .

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) , you can see that HashMap has a method called values()

So you can retrieve the values and you just need to iterate on it.

Edit: The Java arrays and lists starting index is 0.

Answer (score 0):

The method you have accepts an `ArrayList` arg but you are trying to pass the `HashMap`. Maybe you want something like this:

```
public String getSomething (HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map, String key, int n) {

    ArrayList<String> something = (ArrayList<String>)map.get(key);

    return something.get(n);
}
```